# How to determine the number of the non self-intersecting quadrilaterals that can be formed from 4 points?

Tags: geometry

Basically, I'm trying to find the requirements needed to determine whether one or three non self-intersecting quadrilaterals can be formed from 4 given points.

Comment: Do you mean non self-intersecting?

Comment: @okarin Sometimes there are two.  For instance, suppose the vertices are at $(-1,0), (1,0), (0,1)$, and $(0,2)$.

Comment: @chubakueno Yes, I edited my question.

Comment: @Goos I think there are $3$ there actually :)

Comment: @chubakueno oh I see.  You are right.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the complete graph $\Gamma$ on your four vertices, which looks like the shadow of a tetrahedron. A quadrilateral is obtained by deleting two edges that do not share a vertex (i.e., making a circuit on the shadow of the $1$-skeleton of the tetrahedron. If no three of your vertices are collinear, there are two cases:

1. The points are vertices of a convex quadrilateral (i.e., two edges of $\Gamma$ cross), and the only "non-self-intersecting" quadrilateral is the boundary of the convex hull (the crossing edges are the only pair that can be removed).
2. One vertex is inside the triangle formed by the remaining three (i.e., no two edges of $\Gamma$ cross), and there are three (non-convex) quadrilaterals, obtained by removing an edge inside the triangle and the "complementary" edge of the triangle.

If three vertices are collinear, I'd like to see a precise definition of "non-crossing quadrilateral" before attempting to enumerate cases. (Perhaps I've misunderstood your question, since there don't seem to be any cases in which exactly two quadrilaterals arise.)

Comment: You are right. Only 1 or 3 such quadrilaterals can be made from 4 given points.